# Why are Spring CrudRepositories genericized when you can define methods that return any type?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Say I have two JPA entities, `Fizz` and `Buzz` that correspond to `fizzes` and `buzzes` tables in a DB.

What's to stop me from writing something like this:

```
public interface BuzzRepository extends CrudRepository<Buzz,Long> {
    @Query("FROM Fizz WHERE id = :id")
    public Fizz getFizzById(@Param('id') Long id);
}
```

Meaning, what's the point of the genericized `CrudRepository<Buzz,Long>` when I can define my own methods that can return `Fizz`, `String` or anything else I want?

I ask because I feel like I'm missing something fundamental about the intent for how `CrudRepositories` are meant to be used.

Comment: FYI JPQL queries start with `SELECT {alias}`. Ignore that and portaility has just been thrown away

Comment: Thanks @DN1 (+1) but what do you mean by "portability has just been thrown away"? Portability between what?!

Comment: It is no longer JPQL without it obviously, so if someone ever used that against a different JPA provider it would fail. Propagating such stuff means others copy it too. aka Bad practice for little to no benefit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because by default it will create implementations which work with the entity, which it was generified with. For example, it will have method `findAll()` which will return all entities of that type.